# Heatmap in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a data frame `T_mod` with 150 observations and 2920 variables, containing subsurface temperature values in °C over one year. It looks like this:

```
> T_mod[1:10, 1:6]
      t=-24548400 t=-24537600 t=-24526800 t=-24516000 t=-24505200 t=-24494400
z=0.1    9.000187    9.004622    9.009004    9.013332    9.017607    9.021829
z=0.2    8.587763    8.592795    8.597776    8.602705    8.607583    8.612410
z=0.3    8.179728    8.185313    8.190848    8.196334    8.201770    8.207157
z=0.4    7.776561    7.782655    7.788702    7.794702    7.800653    7.806558
z=0.5    7.378704    7.385267    7.391785    7.398256    7.404682    7.411062
z=0.6    6.986564    6.993556    7.000504    7.007408    7.014268    7.021084
z=0.7    6.600512    6.607894    6.615235    6.622533    6.629789    6.637003
z=0.8    6.220886    6.228623    6.236319    6.243975    6.251591    6.259166
z=0.9    5.847995    5.856050    5.864068    5.872046    5.879986    5.887887
z=1      5.482113    5.490454    5.498759    5.507026    5.515257    5.523450
```

The rownames stand for depth. In 10 cm increments from 0.1 m to 15 m underground. Colnames indicate time in elapsed seconds. The cell values are temperatures in °C, for each point in time for a given depth.

I want to create a **heatmap** showing temperatures along time on the x-axis and depth on the y-axis. The plot below is created with the image.plot function in R base graphics using the following code:

```
image.plot(z = t(as.matrix(T_mod[150:1,])), legend.lab = "Temperature (°C)",
           ylab = "Depth (m)", xlab = "Time")
```

[image]

The x axis represents time (one year in 3h intervals) and the y axis represents depth (0 to 15 m in 10 cm increments). Z values are temperatures for a given point in time and a specific depth. Obvisously, the axes ticks and tick labels make little sense as of now. The **problem** is the `image` and `image.plot` functions are somewhat rigid, not allowing to adjust axis ticks, labels, etc.

Now, someone has pointed me towards **ggplot2** for greater flexibility in adjusting plot parameters but I have not used ggplot so far. Consequently, the code below does not work.

```
ggplot(T_mod, aes(x=time, y=Depth, z=Temperature)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Temperature)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=2))+
  ylab("Depth")+
  xlab("Time")+
        # possibly use stat_contour(binwidth = 0.1,aes(colour = ..level..),size=0.1) +
        # ... and scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "Green”) +
        # ... and scale_colour_gradient(low = "black", high = "black",guide = "none")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks=seq(20, 140, 20),limits=c(20,140),labels=lbl_y)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),breaks=seq(124, 2796, 240),limits=c(124,2796),labels=lbl_x)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,150),xlim=c(1,2920))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),plot.title = element_text(size=15))+
  ggtitle("Main title")

> lbl_y
[1]  -2  -4  -6  -8 -10 -12 -14
> lbl_x
 [1] "01 Sep" "01 Okt" "01 Nov" "01 Dez" "01 Jan" "01 Feb" "01 Mrz" "01 Apr" "01 Mai"
[10] "01 Jun" "01 Jul" "01 Aug"
```

The basic issue I believe is that I do not know how to assign depth, time, and temperature from the data frame to the `aes()` call in the first row. [Other examples](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-simple-heatmap-in-ggplot2/) use columns to specify that but the columns in my data frame indicate temperatures at one point in time and as infill I want all temperatures plotted. Any sugggestions on how to plot this with ggplot2 or how to make changes to the image.plot function above that allow axes to be set are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to `gather` your data so that temperature is not stored in multiple columns. `ggplot` is designed to work with tidy data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mentioned in the comment that I think you needed to gather your data, at least if it was presented as shown with time in columns and depth in rows. `ggplot2` is designed to work with tidy data, where each row is an observation and variables are stored in columns. Here, that means you want just three columns, one for each of `depth`, `temp` and `time`, and each row is then a single measurement. You can do this with the code below.

1. Use `gather` to combine all the time columns into a single one
2. Use `separate` to split up the time and row values into just the numeric part
3. Use `select` to drop unneeded variables
4. Use `mutate_at` to convert the values stored as strings into numbers

Then, `ggplot` becomes easy to use. `geom_tile` is designed for three main aesthetics, `x`, `y`, and `fill`. We just call `geom_tile` and map its aesthetics to the variables we want, and produce the plot below. I include `scale_fill_viridis` which changes the colours to perceptually uniform ones, but that isn't necessary. You might not need all these steps if your data isn't stored exactly as shown.

As far as the axis ticks go, you probably do want `scale_x_continuous` but I am not sure what units your time values are in right now.

For more info on [tidy data](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) and on [ggplot](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html), try these chapters.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
tbl <- read_table2(
  "depth   t=-24548400 t=-24537600 t=-24526800 t=-24516000 t=-24505200 t=-24494400
  z=0.1    9.000187    9.004622    9.009004    9.013332    9.017607    9.021829
  z=0.2    8.587763    8.592795    8.597776    8.602705    8.607583    8.612410
  z=0.3    8.179728    8.185313    8.190848    8.196334    8.201770    8.207157
  z=0.4    7.776561    7.782655    7.788702    7.794702    7.800653    7.806558
  z=0.5    7.378704    7.385267    7.391785    7.398256    7.404682    7.411062
  z=0.6    6.986564    6.993556    7.000504    7.007408    7.014268    7.021084
  z=0.7    6.600512    6.607894    6.615235    6.622533    6.629789    6.637003
  z=0.8    6.220886    6.228623    6.236319    6.243975    6.251591    6.259166
  z=0.9    5.847995    5.856050    5.864068    5.872046    5.879986    5.887887
  z=1      5.482113    5.490454    5.498759    5.507026    5.515257    5.523450"
)

tidy_tbl <- tbl %>%
  gather(key = "time", value = "temp", starts_with("t=")) %>%
  separate(depth, c("z", "depth"), sep = "=") %>%
  separate(time, c("t", "time"), sep = "-") %>%
  select(-z, -t) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(depth, time), as.numeric) %>%
  print()
# A tibble: 60 x 3
   depth     time  temp
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.100 24548400  9.00
 2 0.200 24548400  8.59
 3 0.300 24548400  8.18
 4 0.400 24548400  7.78
 5 0.500 24548400  7.38
 6 0.600 24548400  6.99
 7 0.700 24548400  6.60
 8 0.800 24548400  6.22
 9 0.900 24548400  5.85
10 1.00  24548400  5.48
# ... with 50 more rows


ggplot(data = tidy_tbl) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = time, y = depth, fill = temp)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(name = "Temp") + 
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Depth")
```

[image]

Comment: The tidying operation works nicely! As the initial df has 150 observations and 2920 columns, the new df is quite huge with 3 columns and 438000 observations. However, there are two issues with the time column: 1. The listed numerics are converted so as that all “negative” values from the colnames in the initial df (t=-“…”) are positive values now in the new df. E.g. “t=-24548400” is now: 24548400. 2. All colnames from “t=0” to the last column of the initial df (t=6976800) are not displayed in the tidy df but rather filled with NAs. This is the case from observation 340951 to 438000.

Comment: I would like to keep the sign of the former column name numbers and of course have the time column filled up with the according numbers from the former columns, too (instead of having NAs). Both issues can be dealt with manually afterwards, which is what I did for now. It would be nice though if that is accounted for inherently when tidying the data frame in the first place. Any idea on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other statements that the data need to be reshaped to be in tidy format. I just wanted to add that `geom_raster()` rather than `geom_tile()` is generally the better option for large heatmaps. It is optimized for large raster datasets and it is way faster. Example follows below (using the built-in `volcano` data, since I don't have your dataset).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

# create tidy version of volcano data
nx = 87
ny = 61
volcano_data <- data.frame(height = c(volcano), x = rep(1:nx, ny), y = rep(1:ny, each = nx))

# take a look at the dataset. it's indeed tidy.
head(volcano_data)
#   height x y
# 1    100 1 1
# 2    101 2 1
# 3    102 3 1
# 4    103 4 1
# 5    104 5 1
# 6    105 6 1

# plot
ggplot(volcano_data, aes(x, y, fill=height)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  coord_fixed(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

`geom_raster()` also allows you to interpolate between adjacent colors for a smoother appearance. This may or may not be useful to you:

```
ggplot(volcano_data, aes(x, y, fill=height)) + 
  geom_raster(interpolate = TRUE) + 
  coord_fixed(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]